# Use aws EC2 tags for custom filtering the data and send them out to telegraf?

Tags: amazon-ec2, influxdb, telegraf

I am trying to filter the data on specific EC2 instances with a tag called application name to ex:ABCD and send the metrics to Telegraf. Right I have the telegraf taking all the data under the namespace AWS/EC2. Does anyone have any idea on how to filter the data and send it to telegraf? Does it have to do with any changes to be done in telegraf config file?

Answer (score 0):

Generally in all use cases you want clean raw data saved to the db and use indexing and queries to filter the data you are requesting from the database.